# Why multiplying a chunk of audio signal (PCM 16 -bit short array) by a constant is producing robotic output?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, real-time

I have a wav audio file of length 6 seconds. I read it in python using scipy module and it returns a short array of data.

Issue:

I have two scenarios here:

1. Complete 1-D NumPy array of shorts containing my data
2. **21ms** chunks of the same data stored in a list.

When I multiply the **1-D array or 21ms chunks** with a constant number let's say 0.5f. The output amplitude is reduced to half but the voice is clear in both cases.

Now, I have made a window function like hanning or hamming window of length 21ms. If I multiply it with the chunks of 21ms with overlapping or no overlapping and then concatenating the whole result, the output sound is ROBOTIC.

What's the reason for the robotic voice? What am I doing wrong here? I am adding a code snippet. Please have a look. I am stuck here.

```
sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read('nearendimpulse.wav')
no_of_chunks = len(samples) / 1024

chunk = np.zeros(256)
y = []

samples = np.insert(samples, 0, chunk)

for x in range(0, 1024):
    y.append(1 / (15.96 - 14.56 * math.cos((2 * math.pi * x) / (1024 - 1))))


y = np.array(y)
chunks = []
for index in range(0, len(samples), 1024):
    sample = samples[index:index + 1024]
    chunks.append(sample)

length = 1024

final_data = list()

for voice in chunks:
    final_data.append(np.array([(inve * voi) for (inve, voi) in zip(y, voice)]))

final_voice = np.hstack(final_data)

final_voice = final_voice.astype(np.int16)

write('output_final.wav', 48000, final_voice)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1)

ax1.plot(samples)

ax2.plot(y)

ax3.plot(final_voice)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can download the **nearendimpulse.wav** from here : [nearendimpulse.wav](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bjjRbf6V9ALIBuC8LDi3WnnBdEuL6hh5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Common misunderstanding: the window is called Hann, not Hanning. (The one where the formula is one pure cosine period)

Comment: Please post code that we can copy/paste instead of a screenshot. There's a special code button in the toolbar.

Comment: Sorry. Let me update it.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus. Yeah. It's hann.. but basically, I am using the window concept to achieve my desired results.

Comment: I don't see any overlapping in the example. Of course without overlapping, you get periodic extinction of the sound every 21ms (i.e. volume modulation at 47Hz)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus, how much do I overlap in my current scenario?

Comment: wdym? You are concatenating with `np.hstack`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Please elaborate. How much should I overlap two chunks?